# FrameGrabber NullPointerException

Tags: java, opencv, nullpointerexception, javacv

I had the following code to capture an image using the webcam using Javacv. It was working without any issues but now it crashes with a `NullPointerException`.

Code:

```
public class ClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         takeImage();

    }

    public static ImageIcon takeImage() {
        FrameGrabber grabber = null;
        IplImage img = null;
        ImageIcon image = null;
        try {
            grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(0);
        } catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        int i = 0;
        try {
            grabber.start();

            img = grabber.grab();
            if (img != null) {
                cvFlip(img, img, 1);
            }
            // Save image
            image = new ImageIcon(img.getBufferedImage());

            grabber.flush();
            grabber.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Client.showMessage("Error taking image!");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.create(FrameGrabber.java:95)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.createDefault(FrameGrabber.java:118)
    at Main.ClientTest.takeImage(ClientTest.java:33)
    at Main.ClientTest.main(ClientTest.java:24)
```

If anybody can shed some light I would greatly appreciate it, it is sort of a matter of urgency because it's part of my final year project which is due on Monday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted all my .jar imports and reimported them. Everything seems to work now!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the FrameGrabber source code and see if you can piece it together yourself: 
https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/FrameGrabber.java?r=5bbb841a1d9b03328ad0c3dbc723ad6903220d62

If you look at the error it says that the error is happening when takeImage calls FrameGrabber.createDefault(), and when FrameGrabber.createDefault() calls create(). Those two methods are on lines 99 and 123, and the getDefault() method is on line 62. Try walking through those and see if you can figure out what input may have caused the issue.

My guess is that the getDefault() method is returning null (perhaps because there are no classes that extend FrameGrabber), so the create() method throws a null pointer exception when it calls c.getConstructor() because c is null.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look into it. Any idea why it would work then when I came back to it a few days later it doesn't?

Comment: No idea. I would guess that you modified something small elsewhere in your code and didn't think about it, and that may have cause the issue. I've done that plenty of times. Just figure out what things you may have changed recently and see if those are related to FrameGrabber somehow, maybe you'll find something enlightening.